# creation of model object in controller yii

Tags: yii

can any one tell me how to create a model object inside a constructor in yii. I had written the code as belo

```
<?php
class DistributorsController extends Controller
{
   public $layout = '//layouts/column4';
   public $defaultAction = null;

   public function __construct()
   {
     echo '<br>Into constructor';
     parent::__construct('Distributors','distributors');
   }
   public function actionDistributors()
   {
     $this->render("ChannelMask");      
   }
 }
```

?>

But it is displaying only "Into constructor" string and view is not showing in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like any other place if you want to create a new model:

```
$model = new Distributors();
```

or

```
$model = $this->loadModel($id, 'Distributors');
```

if you want to populate your model with existing data, then:

```
$model = Distributor::model()->findAll(); // all there is
```

or

```
$model = Distributor::model()->findByPk($id); // find by primary key
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a model into the Controller.

Create a model, then in Controller, call it like :

```
Distributor::model()->findAll($criteria); //many models
```

or

```
Distributor::model()->findById($id); // one model
```